# this glut sphere won't spin, why? using Visual c++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, animation, glut

This is the complete code I am using. The sphere does not spin like I would expect it to. Normally I program in Java so maybe it is my c++ programming and not GLUT.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

static float angle = 0;

void init(void) 
{
   GLfloat mat_specular[] = { 1.0, .5f, .5f, .5f };
   GLfloat mat_shininess[] = { 15.0 };
   GLfloat light_position[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
   glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   glShadeModel (GL_FLAT);

   glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
   glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, mat_shininess);
   glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);

   glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
   glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
   glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

void display(void)
{

   cout << angle;
   glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   glPushMatrix();
   glRotatef(90, 1, 0, 0);  
   glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1);
   glutSolidSphere (.5, 24, 24);
   glPopMatrix();   
   glFlush ();
   angle += 1;
   glutSwapBuffers();

}

void reshape (int w, int h)
{
   glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
   glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();


   glOrtho (-1.5*(GLfloat)w/(GLfloat)h, 1.5*(GLfloat)w/(GLfloat)h, -1.5, 1.5, -10.0, 10.0);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   glutInit(&argc, argv);
   glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
   glutInitWindowSize (500, 500); 
   glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
   glutCreateWindow (argv[0]);
   init ();
   glutDisplayFunc(display); 
   glutReshapeFunc(reshape);

   glutMainLoop();
   return 0;
}
```

It seems from my debug line 'cout << angle;' that glut is only calling the display function once.
I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 with GLUT

Comment: I'm not too familiar with GLUT, have you tried using some events to force a refresh of the window (like resizing it) to see if it would trigger new calls to `display`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options:

You can manually call `glutPostRedisplay` to ask the main loop to call your display function again, as [documented here](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node20.html).

Or, you can set it to automatically call your display as often as possible by setting it as the idle func with `glutIdleFunc`, as [documented here](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node63.html).

If you're going with the Idle Func, I would definitely suggest you to create a function such as `gameUpdate` or `simulationUpdate` where you manipulate your angle and THEN call `glutPostRedisplay` so that the changes can be rendered.

Comment: this worked. I was wondering if there was a reDisplay func. I just didn't know what it was called. However I have copied and pasted simple animation code that worked fine without using this method. for example this one. http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glut-tutorial/animation/ what is the difference?

Comment: I believe what makes the code in this page work is glutSwapBuffers which would apply the rendering that happened right before between begin / end

Comment: Keep in mind that to swap buffers you need to specify GLUT_DOUBLE in your init, but you already do it so no worries :)

Answer (score 0):

add this to the main

```
glutIdleFunc( display );
```

that tells glut to call your display function when program is in idle state.

Answer (score 0):

The sphere is, in fact, being rotated properly. However, GLUT calls the display functions as few times as possible: it'll be called only when the window has changed.

To solve this, you should use an idle function. An idle function is a function that is called in succession by GLUT. You could do something like:

```
void idle() {
  angle += 1;
  glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

And in your main function:

```
glutIdleFunc(idle);
```

Comment: @ Charles Welton I tried that already to no avail. That was my first thought. Is my variable in scope with the iteration?

Comment: I had forgotten the glutPostRedisplay() call in the original code. It is necessary to redraw the screen.